# Android evenly divide horizontal space into N segments

Tags: android, layout

I have a few buttons (ranges between 1-5) that i would like to show in a horizontal space.

Each space should take up equal amount of space.

The buttons, depending on the state of the current user, will be hidden and shown dynamically.

Ideally, in my java code, i only wish to control the visibility of buttons via setVisibility()

Is there a way to organize my layout, so that the width of my button is always EVENLY distributed across the width of screen?

I thought about using a relative layout, and buttons would line up one by one, but i never get that to work. Alternatively, i could use linearLayout with layout sum, and assign each button a weight of 1. But when i am hiding buttons, the rest of the button do not readjust and take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` with a horizontal orientation. For each of your `Button`s, use these attributes:

```
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

**Do not** put a `weightSum` attribute on the parent `LinearLayout`. Omitting this attribute will cause the buttons to resize as some are shown and hidden.

Comment: Nice i didn't realize it was this easy

Answer (score 0):

Just use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation (should give you an error when you place more than 1 element in LinearLayout and don't mention the orientation attribute) and simply place your buttons. Just include the weight = 1 attribute in your buttons to distribute the space equally.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nero.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="2"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="5"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btn5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);

    btn1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

By setting the visibility of a button to GONE with automatically adjust the size of the remaining buttons with visible visibility. I've tested this piece of code myself to ensure it's functionality.

[image: Result as asked in question]

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach to using `LinearLayout` would be to use a `ConstraintLayout`. Everything in a horizontal chain will be allocated the same amount of space.

Pseudocode below

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <View 
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_leftToLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_rightToLeftOf="@id/two"
    />

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_leftToRightOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_rightToLeftOf="@id/three"
    />

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_leftToRightOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_rightToRightOf="parent"
    />
</ConstraintLayout>
```